# Can this partial application, action creator be rewritten using Object.Assign or the spread operator?

Tags: javascript, redux

Can this be rewritten using Object.Assign or the spread operator?

This is an action creator for a redux call using closures. I believe this syntax can be improved.

```
const create = (actionName) => {
  const type = `${actionName}`;
  const func = ({ status, id = cuid() }) => ({
    type,
    payload: {
      [id]: { status },
    },
  });
  func.type = type;
  return func;
};
```

Usage

```
const addQuestion = createQuestion("add");
const updateQuestion = createQuestion("update");
```

Comment: I don't understand the assignment to the `type` property of the created functions - functions generally should not have properties assigned to them like that. Or is that absolutely required for something?

Comment: type is used for the reducer. Its not known at compile time (Partial Application)

Comment: You could do: `const type = String(actionName); return Object.assign(({ status, id = cuid() }) => ..., { type });` But I'd prefer your current version, it's more readable.

Comment: This would seem to do it, if the odd wrapper, `${actionName}`, is not essential: `const create = (type) => Object .assign (({status, id = cuid()}) => ({type, payload: {[id]: {status}}}), {type})`.  If you really need  ``${actionName}`` for some reason, then you could do it in a defaulted parameter, or you could just use that formulation twice in the body.

Comment: @CertainPerformance: I use such properties on functions fairly often.  It's a convenient programmatically-accessible form of metadata.  One example: a memoization cache.